# Prove (A ∪ B)′ = A′ ∪ B′

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let X be a metric space. A and B are subsets of X.
Here A' and B' are the set of accumulation points. 
I have started the proof, but I am having trouble proving the second part. Here is what I have:
Let x ∈ A′. Then by definition of accumulation points, there is a ball, Br(x) ⊂ A for some r>0, which also contains a point y not equal to x. This point y is also in AUB, so now every Br(x) for some r>0 contains a point of AUB not equal to x, so x ∈ (AUB)′. Now we have A'UB'⊂ (AUB)'.

For the other way around, let x ∈ (AUB)'. Use a proof by contradiction to show that x must also be in A'UB'.

Assume x∉A' which implies or some r>0, there is Br(x) ⊂ A, where A is equal to the empty set or x.

Assume x∉B' which implies or some q>0, there is Bq(x) ⊂ B, where B is equal to the empty set or x.

I am not sure where to go from here

Comment: You write: "Assume x∉A' which implies or some r>0, there is Br(x) ⊂ A, where A is equal to the empty set or x." This is completely non-understandable, especially the last part. The first part is simply wrong. If x∉A', then there exists r > 0 such that $B_r(x)\cap A\subset\{x\}$.

Answer (score 2):

To be more precise, let $X$ be a topological space. $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $X$. $A'$ and $B'$ are the derived sets of $A$ and $B$, respectively.
We have, $(A \cup B)' = A' \cup B'$.

$(A \cup B)' \supset A' \cup B'$ is trivial.
To prove the converse, one has tried the following:

> Let $x\in(A∪B)′ $ and let $U_x$ a neighborhood of $x$.
>   $$ Ux\backslash \{x\}∩(A∪B)≠∅. $$
>
> In particular,
>   $$ (U_x\backslash \{x\}\cap A) \cup(U_x\backslash \{x\} \cap B)\neq\emptyset $$
>   and thus
>   $$ U_x\backslash \{x\}\cap A\neq\emptyset\quad \text{or}\quad U_x\backslash \{x\}\cap B\neq\emptyset. $$
>   Therefore $x \in A′∪B′$.

There is a problem with the above proof. It proved the following statement only:

For all $U_x$ neighborhood of $x, (U_x\backslash \{x\}\cap A \neq \emptyset)$ or $(U_x\backslash \{x\}\cap B \neq \emptyset).$

However, we have to prove the following statement instead:

(for all $U_x$ nbhd of $x, U_x \backslash \{x\} \cap A \neq \emptyset)$ or (for all $U_x$ nbhd of $x, U_x\backslash \{x\} \cap B \neq \emptyset)$

It is rather difficult to prove the above statement directly. By proof of contrapositive, we can prove $(A \cup B)' \subset A' \cup B'$ easily.

Let $x \notin A' \cup B'.$ Then there exists $U_x $ a nhbd of $x$ such that $(U_x \cap A)\backslash \{x\} = \emptyset $ and there exists $V_x $ a nhbd of $x$ such that $(V_x \cap B)\backslash \{x\} = \emptyset $.

Take $G = U_x \cap V_x.$ Then $G$ is a nhbd of $x$ such that $(G\cap A)\backslash \{x\}=\emptyset$ and $(G\cap B)\backslash \{x\}=\emptyset$.
Thus, $(G\cap (A \cup B))\backslash \{x\}=\emptyset$. So, $x \notin (AUB)'.$

Answer (score 1):

Your space is a priori not metrizable, therefore you can't use balls ! Let $x\in (A\cup B)'$ and let $U_x$ a neighborhood of $x$. $$U_x\backslash \{x\}\cap (A\cup B)\neq\emptyset.$$
In particular, $$(U_x\backslash \{x\}\cap A)\cup(U_x\backslash \{x\}\cap B)\neq\emptyset$$
and thus $$U_x\backslash \{x\}\cap A\neq\emptyset\quad \text{or}\quad U_x\backslash \{x\}\cap B\neq\emptyset.$$
Therefore $x\in A'\cup B'$. The other way goes exactly the same !

Comment: Is there a way to prove this without neighborhoods? A and B are nonempty subsets of R